# Unable to get both child elements with xpath from xhtml using xquery in php to manipulate

Tags: php, html, xpath, xhtml, domdocument

The xhtml data I need to get the childNodes from I don't need the child from the TH childNODES

```
<table>some data</table>
<table>
 <tr>
     <td class="c2">PCI Signal Error (SERR#) Enable</td>
     <td>Yes</td>
</tr> 
<tr>
     <td class="c1">Controller Type 1</td>
     <td>CISS</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class="c2">bus type</td>
     <td>CISS</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
     <th><a name="systempcibus5">PCI Bus 31</a></th>
     <td>Device<a href="#system"></a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

below is the latest attempt, I only want to get the textContent for the TD's in the above xml

so I can build a mysql statement to insert the data in mySql

I have tried so many variations over the last week.

I get this error. I won't bore you with all the various things I tried, but I believe this is the closest to what I want.

PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\reports\gec\test1.php on line 40

```
<?php

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = new DomDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
$nodes = $xpath->query('/html/body/table[2]/tr');
//$nodes = $xpath->query("//tr[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' head ') ");
//header("Content-type: text/plain");
        $node_count=$nodes->length ;

for( $i = 1; $i <= intval($node_count); $i++)
{
    $node_td1 = $xpath->query('/html/body/table[2]/tr[$i]/td[1]');
    $node_td2 = $xpath->query('/html/body/table[2]/tr[$i]/td[2]');

    $result1=$node_td1->textContent;

    $result2=$node_td2->textContent;

    echo $result1 . "," . $result2 . "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you could just point out the row itself, then filter them out using that `->tagName`:

```
$dom = new DomDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html);
libxml_clear_errors();
$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
$rows = $xpath->query('/html/body/table[2]/tr');

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    foreach($row->childNodes as $col) {
        if(isset($col->tagName) && $col->tagName != 'th') {
            echo $col->textContent . '<br/>';
        }
    }
    echo '<hr/>';
}
```

Or with using xpath, to reference each row:

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $col1 = $xpath->evaluate('string(./td[1])', $row);
    $col2 = $xpath->evaluate('string(./td[2])', $row);
    echo $col1 . '<br/>';
    echo $col2 . '<br/>';
    echo '<hr/>';
}
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/TYozFf)

Comment: You rock.  Wish I had asked this a week ago. Thank you! However, I learned a ton in the process of trying.  So I can't complain.  I see what has been done, and I will be able to use this a number of ways!